# Why can't I get a working session with vnc4server

Tags: 11.10, vnc, gnome-classic

We have a couple of (identical) Ubuntu 11.10 machines, configured with **gnome-classic**, which we use as remote servers, and let our clients log into personal user accounts we create for them using **vnc4server**.

We configured all the machines in the same way, following a short manual we compiled, describing how to download, install and prepare a few tools and our software.

The connection usually works fine, but today I set up a fresh machine, and experienced problems.

After installing vnc4server, I ran `vncpasswd` and copied the following startup file to `~/.vnc/xstartup`:

```
#!/bin/sh  
unset SESSION_MANAGER  
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS  
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &  
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup  
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources  
xsetroot -solid grey  
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Then, I started `vnc4server` and used two viewers (the Ubuntu Remote Desktop Viewer and Windows RealVNC Client) in two other machines, but instead of getting my desktop, I see an empty window with a grey-ish background pattern like this:

[image]

and the cursor is a bold **X**.

What is wrong with the setup and why don't I get a remote session as expected?

Comment: Please check your firewall settings on both machines for ports 5900 (or whichever port you've configured) as that the service is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, @Hobie, but everything was set correctly, otherwise I won't even be able to connect.

Comment: You might consider using a configuration management tool such as ansible to avoid this sort of problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we found out that the `xstartup` file needs executable permission, which were not set in this machine's configuration. Contrary to other machine, this time I created a new file and typed the contents in instead of just copying a file from another machine, so by default it did not have exe permissions.

`> chmod a+x ~/.vnc/xstartup`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to edit the /root/.vnc/xstartup file so it reads (in your case, the x-terminal-emulator line is your important part to add),

```
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
gnome-session &
```

Comment: Is this a default file that vnc4server reads whenever it starts, before reading the per-user file?

Comment: How is `gnome-terminal` (`x-terminal-emulator`) related to the problem?