# Ubuntu vnc4server no working session only terminal

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10, lightdm, vnc

So I've trid to get xrdp working on Ubutnu Server 13.10 which meant a lot of messing around with lightdm and gdm. So after giving up on xrdp i switched to vnc. I installed vnc4server purged lightdm(as i chose it over gdm) installed ubuntu desktop, and instead of seeing my desktop i get only a terminal or if trying to run either unity or gnome-session in my xstartup i get either a gray screen if the line is not commented out or a patterned screeen both with the X cursor.
What could be the cause of this?

Xstartup:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
 unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

gnome-session-fallback &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
#unity &
gnome-session --session=classic &
```

And my screen looks exactly like in this question :[Why can't I get a working session with vnc4server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120475/why-cant-i-get-a-working-session-with-vnc4server)
Although the answer there hasn't helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

why you load two gnome-session ? if you want to use gnome with vnc server on ubuntu, install these packages and use this xstartup file for gnome

```
# apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

xstartup file

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```